# How to change the downloaded file name when using Cloudfront signed URLs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am generating signed Cloudfront links so that my users can directly access/download files from an S3 bucket.

Considering my file location is: `abcd/file.txt`
Cloudfront URL that is generated: `...cloudfront.net/abcd%2F/file.txt?Expires=...`
Name of the file when saving: `abcd_file.txt`

Is there any way where I can preserve the filename as `file.txt` (i.e the directory path should be excluded from the file name) when it is being saved?

Comment: Would this work? `const strip = path => path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('_') + 1); strip('abcd_file.txt'); // 'file.txt'` It might have issues where the filename actually has an underscore though.

Comment: You can set the content-disposition header

Comment: @jellycsc How do I set the content-disposition header with Cloudfront?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header as metadata to the S3 object. This header will be passed via CloudFront to your browser.

For example, adding the following value will make your browser download the file as `file.txt`:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.txt"
```

The `attachment` directive instructs the browser that it should save the file to disk instead of previewing it in a tab. If you would prefer that the document is previewed in the browser (e.g. a PDF is rendered with the browser's PDF reader instead of downloaded directly), change `attachment` to `inline`.

Depending on which AWS SDK you're using, the code may look something like this:

```
const fileName = 'file.txt'
s3.putObject({
  Bucket: 'my-bucket',
  Key: 'abcd/${fileName}.txt',
  Body: /* ... */,
  ContentDisposition: `attachment; filename="${fileName}"`
}, (err, data) => {
  //
})
```

Watch out for `"` characters etc. in the file name though, if the name is user controlled.  You might want to use something like [`transliteration`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/transliteration).

Note that if you want to change the filename in the `Content-Disposition` header in S3, you'll need to use `copyObject` to make a copy of it with the new correct header.